# Why is a bool's default val (false) not recognized?

Tags: c#, boolean, default, default-value

With this code:

```
bool successfulSend;
const string quote = "\"";
string keepPrinterOn = string.Format("! U1 setvar {0}power.dtr_power_off{0} {0}off{0}", quote);
string shutPrinterOff = string.Format("! U1 setvar {0}power.dtr_power_off{0} {0}on{0}", quote);
string advanceToBlackBar = string.Format("! U1 setvar {0}media.sense_mode{0} {0}bar{0}", quote);
string advanceToGap = string.Format("! U1 setvar {0}media.sense_mode{0} {0}gap{0}", quote);

if (radbtnBar.Checked)
{
    successfulSend = SendCommandToPrinter(advanceToBlackBar);
}
else if (radbtnGap.Checked)
{
    successfulSend = SendCommandToPrinter(advanceToGap);
}
if (successfulSend)
{
    MessageBox.Show("label type command successfully sent");
}
```

I get, "*Use of unassigned local variable 'successfulSend'*"

So I have to change the bool declaration to:

```
bool successfulSend = false;
```

...to get it to compile/run. But isn't false the default value of bool[ean]s? Why does the default value have to be explicitly specified?

There is no complaint with this code:

```
public bool SendCommandToPrinter(string cmd)
{
    bool success; // init'd to false by default
    try
    {
        SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();
        serialPort.BaudRate = 19200;
        serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;
        serialPort.Open();
        serialPort.Write(cmd);
        serialPort.Close();
        success = true;
    }
    catch // may not need a try/catch block, as success defaults to false
    {
        success = false;
    }
    return success;
}
```

### UPDATE

This compiles:

```
bool success;
SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();
serialPort.BaudRate = 19200;
serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;
serialPort.Open();
serialPort.Write(cmd);
serialPort.Close();
success = true;
return success;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "may not need a try/catch block"?

Comment: @BoltClock: Wouldn't the return val be false, anyway, if there was a problem leading up to the setting of "success" to true? See Update above.

Comment: No, if an exception occurs that isn't handled then the method will abort and there will be no return value.

Comment: Put it simple, variables have to be assigned in all paths before you can use/return them.

Comment: @BoltClock: then why does my "Update" code above compile?

Comment: Because you set it to true before returning it. If everything goes smoothly by the time you return, the return value will always be true. If an exception occurs, then there won't be a return value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But isn't false the default value of bool[ean]s?

For *fields* (instance variables and static variables), yes.

But local variables don't have default values, regardless of their type. They *have* to be definitely assigned before they're read.

Comment: The exception to this is local variables that are used to receive an `out` parameter from a method.  They don't need to be definitely assigned provided that there is no control flow that would bypass the call to the method with the `out` parameter.

Comment: @martin_costello: That's not an exception at all. It's just part of the rules of definite assignment. From section 5.3.3.22 of the C# 5 spec: "If the variable v is passed as an out argument (i.e., an argument of the form “out v”) in any of the arguments, then the state of v after expr is definitely assigned. Otherwise; the state of v after expr is the same as the state of v after argn."

Comment: "From section 5.3.3.22 of the C# 5 spec" <= Now I can picture Skeet as a Solicitor (Advocate, Attorney)

Comment: @JonSkeet I meant that they don't have to be definitely assigned by the user in the code as in `var x = blah`, but yes technically they eventually *will* be assigned a definite value (unless there's an exception first).

Comment: @martin_costello: The term "definitely assigned" is a technical one, and I was using it in that technical sense. (For example, non-out *parameters* are definitely assigned on entry to the method, but `out` parameters aren't...) Also note that even without that, there are cases where a variable can be definitely assigned without an assignment statement: `Foo x;` leaves `x` definitely assigned if `Foo` is a struct with no fields.